# How to change source of image on click to one source and back to different source on same click

Tags: javascript, html, image, function, src

When the button is clicked the source of the image must be changed to something and when it is clicked again the source should be changed back to the previous one. Kind of like an animation of sort except that i control it with a button

the code which i have tried and failed is:

```
DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <img id="myImage" src="a.png" alt="a" border="0">

        <button type ="button" onclick="change()">Click Me</button>
    </body>

    <script>

        var x = document.getElementById("myImage")

        function change(){

            if x.src="a.png"

            document.getElementById("myImage").src = "b.png"

            else x.src="a.png"

        }
    </script>

</html>
```

What should i change in my code or is there a simpler code

Comment: You can use a global boolean variable. If true, change src to whatever and change variable to false. If false change src to what ever and variable to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
        var x = document.getElementById("myImage")

        function change(){

            if (x.src == "a.png")
                 x.src = "b.png"
            else 
                 x.src = "a.png"

        }


    </script>
```

**Can also do instead of if statement:**

```
x.src = (x.src == "a.png" ? "b.png" : "a.png");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are locking at:

It took me so long to find the pictures, sorry ㅋㅋㅋ

```js
var imgA = 'http://i.imgur.com/v5o8MW8.jpg'
var imgB = 'http://i.imgur.com/v1Vb6RR.jpg'

var x = document.getElementById("myImage")

function change() {
  x.src = (x.src == imgA ? imgB : imgA);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="change()">Click Me</button></br>
  <img id="myImage" src="http://i.imgur.com/v5o8MW8.jpg" alt="a" border="0">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about `()`:

```
function change(){
            if (x.src="a.png")
            document.getElementById("myImage").src = "b.png"
            else x.src="a.png"

        }
```

MOAR: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Comment: Still wrong. `x.src="a.png"` will evaluate to true always. You're not comparing, rather assigning the value there.

Comment: @asprin i leaved link to 'if statement' )

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to toggle the image you can just use a global variable as below:

```
       var x = 1;

        function change(){
            if (x == 1)
            {
               document.getElementById("myImage").src = "../Images/arrow.png";
               x = 0;
            }
            else 
            {
               document.getElementById("myImage").src="../Images/Add.png";
               x = 1;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Harikrishnan's way is one way of doing it. Another way would be by use of custom `data-*` attributes.

So your HTML would become:

```
<img id="myImage" data-change="b.png" src="a.png" alt="a" border="0">
```

And your Javascript would be:

```
function change(){
    var new_src = x.getAttribute('data-change'); // get the new source
    x.setAttribute("data-change", x.src); // set the custom attribute to current source
    x.src = new_src; // set the image source to new source
}
```

**UPDATE**

Just realized you had syntax error and a typo in your solution.

```
if x.src="a.png"
   document.getElementById("myImage").src = "b.png"
else x.src="a.png"
```

should become

```
if(x.src == "a.png")
   x.src = "b.png"
else
   x.src="a.png"
```

You were missing `()` in your `if` statement and also using a single `=` which will assign a value and not compare values.